# Which iPhone apps will run on the iPad 2 in scaled mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, compatibility, retina-display, ipad-2

I don't own an iPad 2, so I can't test this. Say I've developed an app that uses retina images only, as I made it compatible to iPhone 4 upwards only. Will they run on the iPad 2 in scaled mode?. Technically, the resolution of the iPad 2 non-retina display is larger than the iPhone 4 retina display. But I'm not sure how it will display. Has someone tested this?

Answer (score 0):

The app will run in letter box, scaled size.

Answer (score 0):

It will look the same as a non-retina iPhone app running on the iPad i.e. looking like an iPhone in the middle of the screen. The 'retina' pixels are downsampled to the lower resolution, and if you hit the '2x' button, the downsampled pixels are just doubled in size to fit the screen, even though they could, in theory, map 1-1 with the iPad's pixels.

Answer (score -1):

I am currently working on an HTML5 app and I have used CSS media queries to target different devices, here is a sample of my code:-

```
    <!-- iPhone -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" media="screen 
    and (resolution: 163dpi)" href="~/content/images/iOS-57.png" />

    <!-- iPad (portrait) --><!-- iPad (landscape) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="~/content/images/iOS-72.png" />

    <!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) --><!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="~/content/images/iOS-144.png" />

    <!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="~/content/images/iOS-114.png" />

    <!-- iPhone -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPhone 5 -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (portrait) -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png"
          media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
             and (orientation: portrait)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (landscape) -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png"
          media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
             and (orientation: landscape)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png"
          media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
             and (orientation: portrait)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) -->
    <link href="~/content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png"
          media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
             and (orientation: landscape)
             and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your app to look as ipad application you need to add universal property in target configuration. If target is only Iphone it will be shown always in small window.